Boundedness of an Implicit Function (Algebraic Riccati Equation)
Consider the algebraic Riccati Equation which is dependent on some parameter $$ a = [a_{min},a_{max}] \in \cal A$$ $$ P(a)A(a)+A^T(a)P(a)-P(a)BR^{-1}B^TP(a)+Q = 0. $$ It is assumed that $(A(a),B)$ is stabilizable and  $(A(a), \sqrt{Q})$ is detectable for all $a \in \cal A$
The goal is to show that the solution of the CARE P(a) for $\forall  A(a),B,Q,R$  is bounded in the interval a. I think because the CARE is an implicit Function I somewhat have to use the implicit Function theorem. But I am not sure how to use it correctly and if it really helps me for my problem.
It would be also interesting to show if the mapping $f:a \mapsto P(a)$ is continues and unique. Is it even possible to show ?
Does someone have an idea how I can start with this problem ?
Thanks in advance!

What are the assumptions on $A$ on the controllability of $(A,B)$?

The assumptions are that for all parameter a (A,B) is always controllable and observable.
Thanks for the hint, I forgot to write it.

Do you want to find a solution $P(a)$, $\forall A(a),B,Q,R$?

Your question, as currently written, is not completely clear. Namely you use both $A$ for the set of $a$ and the matrix function $A(a)$. Furthermore, you ask about the boundedness of "the function". But what function are you referring to? The solution to the ARE: $P(a)$?

I edited the question and hope that it is more clear now, sorry for the confusion.

Assuming that the pair $(A(a),B)$ is stabilizable and that the pair $(Q^{1/2},A(a)$ is detectable for all $a\in\cal A$, then for all $a\in\cal A$, there exists a stabilizing solution $P_s(a)$ for the Riccati equation
$$
P(a)A(a)+A(a)^TP(a)-P(a)BR^{-1}B^TP(a)+Q = 0.
$$
Since $\cal A$ is compact, then we have that the set of stabilizing solutions $\{P_s(a):a\in\cal A\}$ is necessarily bounded as it consists of a set of matrices  with finitely valued entries. Note that, by definition of stabilizing solutions, we have that $A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP(a)$ is Hurwitz stable for all $a\in\cal A$.

In case, you want to say more. I need to assume that $A(a)$ is a differentiable function of $a$. Define the function $F(P,a)$ as
$$
F(P,q):=PA(a)+A(a)^TP-PBR^{-1}B^TP+Q
$$
and, as you rightly pointed out, we have that $F(P,a)=0$. The Frechet derivative of the function $F$ at $(P,a)$ as
$$
F'(P,a)[dP,da]=dP(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP)+(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP)^TdP+(A'(a)^TP+PA'(a))da
$$
This derivative is equal to zero since $F(P,a)=0$. The implicit function theorem requires that the map
$$
J:dP\mapsto dP(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP)+(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP)^TdP
$$
is a Banach space isomorphism from the set of symmetric matrices onto itself. Now, we can use the first part of the answer and consider $P=P_s(a)$. In that case, we get that the equation $J(dP)=Y$ has the solution
$$
dP = \int_0^\infty e^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]^Ts}Ye^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]s}ds
$$
for all symmetric matrices $Y$. This shows that the map $J$ is invertible and that we have
$$
dP=-\left(\int_0^\infty e^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]^Ts}(A'(a)^TP+PA'(a))e^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]s}ds\right)da
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\dfrac{dP}{da}=-\int_0^\infty e^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]^Ts}(A'(a)^TP_s(a)+P_s(a)A'(a))e^{[(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a)]s}ds.
$$
We can also just keep the Lyapunov equation formulation
$$
P'_s(a)(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a))+(A(a)-BR^{-1}B^TP_s(a))^TP'_s(a)+(A'(a)^TP_s(a)+P_s(a)A'(a))=0
$$
where $P_s(a)$ is the stabilizing solution of the Riccati equation.

Thank you very much for helping me!
So mathematically it makes sense to me, but I'm not sure what exactly the second part says about the problem. Doesn't the implicit function theorem just say: that if a solution exists at a point, that in a small neighborhood there is a unique solution to the equation $F(x,y) = 0$ ?My Math Prof says that this theorem is important but it's not clear to me what the use of it is in general.
Another question is, what is if A(a) is not continues because the value a changes erractic/discrete. Is it even possible to calculate the Frechet-Derivative ?

The second part mostly says that the solution is differentiable with respect to the parameter $a$ and how this derivative could be computed. It is also defines a differentiable equation that describes how the solution changes with the parameter. The implicit function theorem is about the local existence of a solution to an implicit function, here $F(P,a)=0$. The theorem can also say more about the solution, such as the local differentiability, as done here. If the domain for $a$ is not continuous, then we need to use something else.
